# Multiply vec3 with mat4 using glm

Tags: c++, glm-math

At the moment, I convert the `vec3` to `vec4`, multiply it with the matrix, and then cast it back to `vec3`

Code:

```
glm::vec3 transformed = glm::vec3(matrix * glm::vec4(point, 0.0))
```

It works, but I think it is not the good way to calculate it. Is it possible to apply a `mat4` on a `vec3`, without casting it to `vec4` and back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with OpenGL it is very wise to stick with [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). For 3D space these are 4D vectors where normally the fourth element equals 1. When you do this all your calculations are in 4 dimensional space, so no conversions needed anywhere.

Also note that in your example, you will actually lose any translation that may have been recorded in the transformation matrix. If you want to keep this you'll need to use 1 for the 4th element, not 0.

[Appendix F of the Red Book](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/appendixf.html) describes how and why homogeneous coordinates are used within OpenGL.

Comment: I see `0.0` and `1.0` at the 4th coordinate too. Which is one correct? The zero 4th coordinate seems to be the correct one, for example if I calculate the length of a vector

Comment: In this case 1.0 is correct, otherwise you lose the fourth column of your transformation matrix, which would normally contain the translation part of the transformation.

Comment: The length of the vector is always correct, as it is defined on the vector, not on the 3D space that you intend to represent. If you want to find the distance to origin of a 3D point represented you need to calculate sqrt((x^2 + y^2 + z^2)/w^2) where the 4D vector is [x y z w]. As you can see 0 doesn't make sense here as you'd get a divide by 0, therefore [x y z 0] is not a point in 3D space in homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: As far as I know, the length of a 4D vector is defined as: `sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z+w*w)`

Comment: Exactly, that is the length of the 4D vector in 4D space, but it is *not* the distance to origin of the 3D point represented by the homogeneous coordinate. These are different things.

Comment: Added a link to appendix f of the red book which describes homogeneous coordinates within OpenGL

Comment: The problem I am facing with changing my vectors to be 4D in general is that OpenGL itself expects 3D vectors, e.g. in `glm::lookAt`.

Comment: @matec this is easily solved with `glm::vec3(your_homogenous coordinate)` to convert your homogenous coordinates into plain 3D coordinates when you call `glm::lookAt`

Comment: if vec3 represents a point, w should be 1, otherwise, if it represents a direction, w should be 0

Answer (score 0):

mat4 is a 4 by 4 matrix, so you need a 4 dimension vector to multiply it.

That 4th dimension is really useful for 3D math, to distinguish between 3D space points (1) and 3D vectors (0)

Here I missing lots of operator, but I hope that you get the idea.

```
class point3
{
public:
    vec4 p;

public:
    point3();
    point3(const point3& rhs);
    point3(const point3& rhs);
    point3(float x, float y, float z);
    point3& operator=(const point3&rhs);
    vector3 operator-(const point3&rhs);
    point3 operator+(const vector3&rhs);
    point3& operator+=(const vector3&rhs);
};

point3::point3():p.x(0), p.y(0), p.z(0), p.w(1)
{

}
point3::point3(const point3& rhs):p(rhs.p)
{

}
point3::point3(const point3& rhs):p(rhs.p)
{

}
point3::point3(float x, float y, float z):p.x(x), p.y(y), p.z(z), p.w(1)
{

}
point3& point3::operator=(const point3&rhs)
{
    return (p=rhs.p);
}
vector3 point3::operator-(const point3&rhs)
{
    vector3 result;
    result.p=(p-rhs.p);
    return result;
}
point3 point3::operator+(const vector3&rhs)
{
    point3 result;
    result.p=(p+rhs.p);
    return result;
}
point3& point3::operator+=(const vector3&rhs)
{
    p=(p+rhs.p);
    return p;
}

class vector3
{
public:
    vec4 p;

public:
    vector3();
    vector3(const vector3& rhs);
    vector3(const vector3& rhs);
    vector3(float x, float y, float z);
    vector3& operator=(const vector3&rhs);
    vector3 operator-(const vector3&rhs);
    point3 operator-(const point3&rhs);
    point3 operator+(const point3&rhs);
    vector3 operator+(const vector3&rhs);
    vector3& operator+=(const vector3&rhs);
};
vector3::vector3():p.x(0), p.y(0), p.z(0), p.w(0)
{
}
vector3::vector3(const vector3& rhs):p(rhs.p)
{
}
vector3::vector3(const vector3& rhs):p(rhs.p)
{
}
vector3::vector3(float x, float y, float z):p.x(x), p.y(y), p.z(z), p.w(0)
{
}
vector3& vector3::operator=(const vector3&rhs)
{
    p=rhs.p;
    return p;
}
vector3 vector3::operator-(const vector3&rhs)
{
    vector3 result;
    result.p=(p-rhs.p);
    return result;
}
point3 vector3::operator-(const point3&rhs)
{
    point3 result;
    result.p=(p-rhs.p);
    return result;
}
point3 vector3::operator+(const point3&rhs)
{
    point3 result;
    result.p=(p+rhs.p);
    return result;
}
vector3 vector3::operator+(const vector3&rhs)
{
    vector3 result;
    result.p=(p+rhs.p);
    return result;
}
vector3& vector3::operator+=(const vector3&rhs)
{
    p=(p+rhs.p);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: So I should store my 3D vectors in vec4?

Comment: Usually I make a wrapper, two classes, point3 and vector3 that inside are vec4, and then overload the operators to work properly for each one, it is not much work becouse basically you have all the hard work done by glm,

Comment: As trivia, that 4th dimension is only used to be able to concatenate all the transformation into a one single matrix. this way, the translation matrix only affects to 4D vectors that have their w coordinate with a 1 value

Comment: This post maybe welp you to understand why is important to diferenciente that w dimension [math](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14115/do-i-need-the-w-component-in-my-vector-class)

Comment: "Usually I make a wrapper" How is it possible? Could you please give me some keywords, using I could find some example code or tutorial about it?